# Is it possible to have a Conditioned `firedate` for UILocalNotification?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to have a conditioned firedate time for my local notifications, however when I tried these two ways it didn't fail but it still didn't work. So, I was wondering if I'm able to do such a thing?

**Note:** startTime and endTime are times from date pickers.

```
-(void) TEST {

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
components.hour   = 3;
components.minute = (components.minute + 1) % 60;
components.second = 57;

NSDate *fire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]  init] ;
if (notif == nil)
    return;

if (fire < startTime.date) {


notif.fireDate =fire ;
    notif.repeatInterval= NSMinuteCalendarUnit ;
    notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"You are missed!"] ;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif] ;


    }

if (fire > endTime.date) {


    notif.fireDate =fire ;
    notif.repeatInterval= NSMinuteCalendarUnit ;
    notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"You are missed!"] ;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif] ;


}}
```

**OR**

```
-(void) TEST {

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
components.hour   = 3;
components.minute = (components.minute + 1) % 60;
components.second = 57;

NSDate *fire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]  init] ;
if (notif == nil)
    return;

if (fire > startTime.date & fire < endTime.date) {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications] ;
}

else {
    notif.fireDate =fire ;
    notif.repeatInterval= NSMinuteCalendarUnit ;
    notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"You are missed!"] ;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif] ;


}}
```

**Thanks**

If not, what would be the easiest way to make such a condition?

Comment: Did you log the fire date? If you use the minute from the component you need to load the minute when getting the component from the calendar + date (NSMinuteCalendarUnit).

Comment: Yes I did log it and it never goes inside the if condition

Comment: Try `if ([fire timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime.date] >= 0) // fire is before start`.

Comment: @relikd Thanks, but still not working! :/

Comment: @Bonnie **none of your answer worked** and I guess there is no solutions for such a thing as I couldn't find anyway to perform notifications cancellation on a specific time while in the background. **However, you deserve the 100 points for your hard work. Thank you.**

Comment: thanks mate, pleasure .but if you ever find something do post it here.

Answer (score 0):

use the NSDate `Compare:` method instead of `if(fire > startTime.date)`

```
if([fire compare: startTime.date] == NSOrderedDescending) // if start is later in time than end
{
    // do something
}
```

From the class reference:

```
If:
The receiver and anotherDate are exactly equal to each other, NSOrderedSame.
The receiver is later in time than anotherDate, NSOrderedDescending.
The receiver is earlier in time than anotherDate, NSOrderedAscending.
```

so for your condition

```
if (fire > startTime.date & fire < endTime.date) {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications] ;
}
```

you can use

```
if([fire compare: startTime.date] == NSOrderedDescending && [fire compare: endTime.date]== NSOrderedAescending)
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications] ;
}
```

this will cancel the all local notifications if fire is between the selected start and end date

```
else {
// Fire the notifications
}
```

also have a look at the link this is similar to what you need [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773544/activate-local-notification-based-on-time-in-the-background)

Comment: unfortunately, notification is still firing and it didn't cancel!! I heard you can't have constrains on `UILocalNotification` is it true?

Comment: please tell what exactly you need to do, and what is not working, my assuption: startTime and EndTime is the time between which u notifications will not be triggered.? right.?? acording to this code if the fireDate is between the start and end time, the Notification will not be created, so no possibility of it triggering. Do you want to want to just cancel all notifications already created that fall in the DoNotDisturb time frame.?? or u just dont want the user to allow creating new UILocalnotication between the DoNotDisturb time frame

Comment: Your assumptions are right. I want to cancel the notifications between startTime and endTime. So, will this code be able to cancelAllLocalNotifications in the background when it was already scheduled? Because I tried it and it didn't work!

Comment: Here is the scenario, I have a local notification that is scheduled for a repeat interval every hour. I want when the user choose startTime and endTime these notifications will stop automatically during the night and reschedule again without the need to open the app. How can I do that? Is it possible with this code?

Comment: there is no straght way of doin that but, have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773544/activate-local-notification-based-on-time-in-the-background exatcly what you need

Comment: That was actually my question but when I tried I couldn't get it to work because I have 24 hourly interval repeated notification and he is asking me to make it daily repeat interval. If there isn't a straight way then how do you do it? Considering I need to fire a notification every 5 minute.

Answer (score 0):

what i, will try do do is, when the sleep Time starts,call a method eg: `goingToSleep:`, you can use 
`dispatch_later` or `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` for that,

in `goingToSleep:`

```
NSArray* localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
                                              scheduledLocalNotifications];
for (UILocalNotification *notification in localNotifications)
{
    if([fire compare: startTime.date] == NSOrderedDescending &&
       [fire compare: endTime.date]== NSOrderedAescending)
    {
```

This is the important part

- get all the properties of the notification
- create a NSDictionary of those properties
- Add the NSDictionary to an array
- and save that array into a plist.([Save Array to Plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356929/how-to-save-nsmutable-array-into-plist-in-iphone))
- and then Cancel that notification using

  ```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
  }
  ```

}

then after SleepTime is over 
, again call a method eg: `wakingUp:`

then in `wakingUp:`

- read the array of NSDictionary we saved.
- again Create UILocalnotifications using those same Properties.

this way, no UILocalNotifications will trigger during sleep time. one issue can be executing those methods, if the Application is not memory.

**EDIT** [To have long Running Appicaions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674004/ios-keep-application-running-in-background).

Comment: Thank you very much the code have worked partially. I tried the delay property and it worked while the app is running. However, I'm still trying to understand the Plist, NSDictionary and the arrays so I can make it work on the background. I have 2 questions: do you have any links to tutorial explains your answer? Or can you point me to elaborated answers?

Comment: What do you mean by "one issue can be executing those methods, if the Application is not memory"? What is a memory application?

Comment: Unfortunately, performSelctor:withObject:afterDelay won't work in background after the first 10 minutes :/

Comment: exactly..dats wat i meant when i said "one issue can be executing those methods, if the Application is not memory". ie the application is closed by the os. find a way to keep it running, i have posted a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354759/nstimer-stops-in-the-background-after-some-time/16354843#16354843), have a look at my other answer

Comment: Why have you answered twice? You shouldn't be doing this you should have update your original answer.

Comment: I know that bro, but you should look at the question. my first answer was only related to the conditions that were not working as required. and my second answer was for the bounty "If not, what would be the easiest way to make such a condition?". i had to post two answer's because, a person visiting the question later on would not understand. And its not necessary to always update the previous answer "specially if both are completely different and correct". otherwise Stack Overflow wouldn't give the provision to add two answer's.

Comment: To be honest mate all it looks like is you've answer the question twice and that's it. There isn't anything to say why. Maybe you should include the reason why in your answer. Just my opinion, up to you if you do include it. It's not very common for users to answer twice they generally just update there original answer and make it clear that it is an edit and the reason for the edit.

Comment: if you would have read the question and both the answer's properly you would have had a different opinion, leave it mate, move on.

Comment: I have just re-read the question and both answers and I see no reason at all now why this needs two answers from you this could definitely have been one answer. If anything I am going to question how this answer (not the first one) actually answers the question. If something was included in the reason for the bounty then that should be included somewhere as no one knows the reason for this. I am now considering a downvote because of both of the reasons stated in comments.

Comment: hahaha. I just saw your profile, r u crazzy man. even when i said leave it and move on, ur still stuck at me posting two answer's, and now down voting it for the reason of posting two ans rather than the quality of the answer's itself and ur about me is funny naming people in ur profile.haha.. u seriously need medication mate, i now understand wat's wrong with you, ur downvote doesnt affect me at all,it'l just confuse others. Go out there and do something constructive mate, rather than complaining like a baby. This will be my last comment, i don't have anymore time to waste on people like you.