# Cancelling single occurence of repeating local notification

Tags: ios, notifications, local

I have scheduled repeating local notification for, let's say, 10.00 am. Repeat interval is one week. Is it possible to cancel programatically only single ocurrence of repeating notification? For example, it's 9.30 am, user has tapped checkbox and (programatically) cancelled notification, so it won't be displayed on 10.00, but will be displayed next week?

Comment: Not quite understanding your problem...but [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5866202/1383704)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It is not possible** to cancel single occurrence of a repeating local notification. When you are scheduling a notification in repeating mode, you are creating one and only one notification even though it repeats. It counted as one. So what you can do is if the user tapped the switch **cancel that notification and reschedule it** in such a way that it will start from next week 10 am. If you need any help on that i will help you. Give a try first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you confirmed my previous research. Rescheduling won't be problem, but thanks for your kindness.