# How to add repeat count or expire date for Local notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

When I log the description of the local notification

```
`<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x1edd4d40>{fire date = Thursday, September 26, 2013, 11:15:00 AM India Standard Time, time zone = Asia/Kolkata (GMT+05:30) offset 19800, repeat interval = 0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Thursday, September 26, 2013, 11:15:00 AM India Standard Time, user info = {
    UID = "38BF41F8-05D3-48E2-A20F-7B84609F4E85";
}}`
```

And I found "repeat count" parameter. Is there any option to set the repeat count such that it will repeat for this no of count and expired

Comment: please explain what you want i cnt get you :(

Comment: asking for Is it possible to cancel local notification after one week when repeat interval is NSDaysCalendarUnit like that?

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround was asked in this question. [Cancelling single occurence of repeating local notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333687/cancelling-single-occurence-of-repeating-local-notification)

But, as this suggests I dont think it is possible to have a repeating Local notification distinguished by its repeat count.

Answer (score 0):

You couldnt set any repeat count for this purpose. But instead you can modify the fireDate with necessary checking after receiving notification and then it can be scheduled again.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification    {

    localNotif = notification;

    int no_of_days = [self getNumberOfDaysToNextAlarmInDays];
    int day = 24*60*60;
    NSTimeInterval interval = day *no_of_days;
    localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

}



-(int)getNumberOfDaysToNextAlarmInDays {

    //do the necessary calculations here

    return count ;
}
```

A small problem here is it only works when the *didReceiveLocalNotification* invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the repeat count as a number. When notification fired in `Appdelegate` `didReceiveLocalNotification` method will be called. In that method you can get the repeat count. There you can decrease the repeat count and reschedule your notification. if the repeat count is 0 then you no need to reschedule that `notification`.

For example:

```
if ([[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"repeat"]intValue] != 0) {
   //You can again schedule your notification here with decrementing the repeat count.
}else{

}
//Here you can cancel the current notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelLocalNotification:notification];
```

Hope this helps :)