# Stop Repeating Local Notification iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilocalnotification

I have initialize local notification for every 30 seconds. and i want to stop repeating it once user has pressed button for stop Local Notification.

problem is i couldnt find a way of doing it. it keeps repeating every 30 seconds

This is how i have sheducled localnotification

```
  // Schedule the notification
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:30];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Testing Repeating Local Notification";
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.repeatCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    localNotification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitSecond;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

I have tried `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];` . but it dosent work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancelling single occurence of repeating local notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333687/cancelling-single-occurence-of-repeating-local-notification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

just removed `localNotification.repeatCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];` from above code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you set `repeatInterval` to 0. According to documentation if it is set to zero notification will be fired once. So when stop button is pressed you can do following

```
localNotification.repeatInterval = 0;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove notification when you get notification in application active state.

just like

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        NSLog(@"Application is active");

        /*
        ...
        do some process
        ...
        */

        //remove notification
        [application cancelLocalNotification:notification];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Application is inactive");
    }
}
```